# general form to big o notation - recurrences

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am struggling to understand how to convert a general form to the final proof of the big.

For example assume the recurrence `T(n-2) + 1` the general form is (my guess) `T(n - 2k) + k` but how would I show that this is big O of something

`1` `t(n-2) + 1`
`2` `t(n-4) + 2` \

I am using the iteration method by the way and base case is T(0) = 1

The full question is below

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvP4L.png) (this is not homework but last years midterm which he said he will not be giving the solution)

Comment: Do you mean $T(n)= T(n-2)+1$ and $T(n)=T(n-k)+k$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Tulip is my general form wrong?

Comment: I am trying to understand the statement. Generally (but not always), a recursion is given as an equation in which the current value (i.e. $T(n)$) is given in terms of the previous values (like $T(n-1)$ or $T(n-2)$).

Comment: @Tulip I added the inital question to the post

Comment: Okay, so in this case $t(n)=t(n-2)+1$. Hint: Start by considering the case where $n$ is even, and compute $t(2), t(4),\dots , t(10)$. You should see a simple pattern emerging.

Comment: @Tulip while subing for n is see that it is increasing by 2 ( 1, 3, 5, 7, 9) each time. I understand this part but I am confused on the fact of what to do with general function of which I have determined to be `T(n-2k) + 1`

Comment: You have the pattern $T(n)=T(n-2)+1=T(n-4)+2=\cdots=T(n-n)+n/2$, so $T(n)=T(0)+n/2=1+n/2$

Comment: @MengchunZhang so the answer would be O(N) right? that was clear thank you

Comment: @GrandmaKisses Yes you got it!